# AttributeErrors, Tuples and other things nice

Tags: python, module, python-2.7, tuples, attributeerror

I can't say I fully understand the script, because classes go beyond me as yet. Anyway, I've downloaded the py-omegle module [from here](http://code.google.com/p/py-omegle/downloads/detail?name=Omegle.py&can=2&q=) . And I don't seem to be able to get it to run. 
Hoping that I don't need to post the whole class including functions, the part in particular that I'm having trouble with pertains to urllib2 - so I guess It's not too specific an issue - the line that causes all of the issues is:

```
self.connector = urllib2.build_opener(processor),urllib2.HTTPHandler(debuglevel=1)
```

and it's not letting me:

```
#omegle.py
[ln33] self.connector.addheaders = [
[ln34]     ('User-agent',user_agent)
[ln35]     ]

       # or 

[ln98] self.id = self.connector.open(self.url+'start',data={}).read().strip('"')
```

Both return AttributeError:

```
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'addheaders'

# and further down
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'open'
```

Could someone please explain how to fix this? I'm sure it has something to do with the first line I posted. The entire source of the ONLY file in this module can be [accessed here](http://py-omegle.googlecode.com/files/Omegle.py).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's a case of misplaced parentheses.

The first line:

```
self.connector = urllib2.build_opener(processor),urllib2.HTTPHandler(debuglevel=1)
```

creates a tuple consisting of

```
 urllib2.build_opener(processor)
```

and

```
 urllib2.HTTPHandler(debuglevel=1)
```

And then assigns this tuple to `self.connector`.

Comment: That has fixed it! I commented out the HTTPHandler portion. Thank you! - I've overcome one error, onwards-forth! I am now receiving a  TypeError stating that "self.url+'start',data=""" in ln98 have to be a string. I don't understand how they're not! Gah, old modules. Thank you for your help, anyway! :)

Comment: @abkai: instead of commenting out the `HTTPHandler` you can move it *inside* of the `build_opener()` call; move the closing parenthesis next to `processor` to the end of the line: `urllib2.build_opener(processor,urllib2.HTTPHandler(debuglevel=1))`.